# Android horizontal progress bar?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I'd like to implement a progress bar like this

[image]

Please help how can I do it or if there is a library

Comment: Hello @yousseefhassan,

Have you implemented this custom progressbar?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I saw that a lot of people are looking on this post so I thought that I should edit it and share an example:

Note (this example is not complete, it's still in progress but I guess it's a starting point)

GitHub: [Github Example](https://github.com/ManolescuSebastian/AndroidCustomHorizontalProgressBar/tree/master)

[image]

The important part in this example is below:
Create in drawable a xml file custom_progress_bar_horizontal.xml and add the content below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="3dip"
                android:top="3dip"
                android:left="3dip"
                android:right="3dip"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#2a2b2f"
                android:centerColor="#2a2b2f"
                android:centerY="0.50"
                android:endColor="#2a2b2f"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners
                    android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#ff0e75af"
                    android:endColor="#ff1997e1"
                    android:angle="90" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Add the following code in styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progress_bar_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">10dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
</style>
```

After you have added the style in your activity layout add:

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/customProgress"
        style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

The progress dispaly below in a frame it's a little tricky because you need to extend the ProgressBar class and make the changes there.

I will leave here some examples and notify when I will add them in my github project.

Great example if you want to disaply the progress in your way:
[NumberProgressBar](https://github.com/daimajia/NumberProgressBar)

Other progress bar examples:

[Custom progress bar 1](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.ro/2013/01/how-to-create-custom-progress-bar-and.html)

[Custom progress bar 2](http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/)

[Custom progress bar 3](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/custom-progress-bar-in-android.html)

**UPDATE:**

Also check [DiscreteSeekBar](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar) this is a great github project.

Gradle: compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'

**Update #2**

Maybe this library will be also useful
https://github.com/ManolescuSebastian/USeekbar

Cheers,

Comment: I searched for this topic and got this post. :)