# Set Progress bar progress color programatically

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am showing the progress bar while downloading files.I want to set the color(HTML color code) of the progress which comes from the server and may vary the color code time to time.
how do i meet the requirement.

[image].

For example for the above image i want to change yellow color and set the color which comes server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745814/android-change-horizonal-progress-bar-color

Comment: @HareshChhelana I want to set color through code.

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar if use colorfilter,color is set ,but not able to see the progress.I have tried using different modes too.

Comment: @421 was my example usefull?

Comment: @Meher What makes you think the ProgressBar spec has an api to set colors programatically?

Answer (score 1):

So...I made a sample project that changes the progress color and you also can change the background progress bar color.

First create a custom progress bar xml file.

**custom_progressbar.xml**

```
<!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#000001"
            android:centerColor="#0b131e"
            android:centerY="1.0"
            android:endColor="#0d1522"
            android:angle="270"
            />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#2A98E1"
                android:centerColor="#2A98E1"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="#06101d"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Activity Layout:

**activity_my.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MyActivity">


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/myProgress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progressTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="None"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The test activity:

The important part is this:

**Drawable draw=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar);
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(draw);**

**MyActivity.java**

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private int progressStatus = 0;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);



    init();
    initProgresBar();

}


public void init(){

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressTextView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.myProgress);
    Drawable draw=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar);
     // set the drawable as progress drawable
    progressBar.setProgressDrawable(draw);

}

public void initProgresBar(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 1;
                // Update the progress bar and display the

                //current value in the text view
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                        textView.setText(progressStatus+"/"+progressBar.getMax());
                    }
                });
                try {
                    // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.

                    //Just to display the progress slowly
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

And the output will be this:

[image]

Hope this is what you where looking for. Cheers

For more info you will find this usefull: [stack progress bar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177006/android-horizontal-progress-bar)

Comment: first i tried with COLOR.RED.the whole progress bar is red and i am not able to see the progress.

Comment: OK I will come back with a sample example:)

Comment: Thank you for your effort.but this progress bar is set in xml.how do i change the color using java code.

Comment: Why are you putting `<item>` without layer-list element?

Comment: How do you change colour of progress bar when its completely filled?

Answer (score 0):

```
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#YourColorHex"), Mode.SRC_IN);
```

[Tutorial for Customizing ProgressBar](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/custom-progress-bar-in-android.html)

**EDIT:**

http://miroprocessordev.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-how-to-change-progress-bar.html

Comment: if i set a color,color is completely filled.Not able to see the progress.Any other point i m missing ?

Comment: are you using `progressBar.setProgress(0);` ?

Comment: Yes before the start of the download.

Comment: i have edited my answer, you will need to use custom style xml

Comment: edited answer is picked from xml.which is not recommended in my case as color code will come from xml.