# Show Progress using ProgressBar for WebViewClient

Tags: android, webview, android-progressbar, webviewclient

I am using WebViewClient to load web pages and I would like to show progress bar for my code. My code isn't loading the progress gradually. It only shows 100% progress. How do I set the progress based on web page loading time?

For my purpose I have to load just "https://www.google.com" on a WebView only. Please help. Thank you. Code is shown below :

Activity file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int vc = Color.parseColor("#feca01");


    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.determinateBar);
    progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
            vc, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://deelay.me/5000/http://www.google.com");

}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
    {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.incrementProgressBy(10);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       // progressBar.setProgress(0);
    }
 }
```

}

XML file

`

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/determinateBar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp" />

<WebView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_weight="0.91"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    />
```

`

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849347/adding-a-progress-dialog-in-a-webview) answer.

Comment: Refer the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911185/set-progress-bar-progress-color-programatically and check if it suits your requirement

Comment: @KunalChawla, it didn't work. :-\

Comment: @ThillaiK. It didn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this my friend

```
WebView webView;
ProgressBar progressBar;

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);

progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
progressBar.setMax(100);
progressBar.setProgress(1);

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }



        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

> Layout

```
 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="1"
    android:theme="@style/ProgressbarTheme" />
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [FinestWebView](https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android).

Using this you only need to load your webview by calling -

```
new FinestWebView.Builder(this).titleDefault("The Finest Artist")
                .show("http://thefinestartist.com");
```

[image]

Comment: Really interesting. Will try it out right now! Thanks :)