# a progress bar in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

i have seen many progress bar code but i was not able to apply it on my app , pls help me make a good progress bar . the progress bar should show until webpage load in webView in fragment . pls make a code according to my code , sorry but im new to android and just  started pls help a newbie

**fragment code**

```
public class BlankFragment2 extends Fragment {

    public Handler h;
    TextView txt;
 Bundle webViewBundle;
    public AdView adView;
    public WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mWebView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
    public BlankFragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view
                = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blank_fragment2, container, false);
        txt=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hi);
        Runnable r=new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("bf", "fd");
                h.postDelayed(this, 300);
                if (txt.isShown()){
                    txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
                else{
                    txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

        };



        mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.hu);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        this.mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.brainyquote.com/topics/love");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad9View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad10View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad13View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad14View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad11View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad12View);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn1);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn2);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn3);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn4);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.earn5);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                        && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        && mWebView.canGoBack())
                {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        webViewBundle = new Bundle();
        mWebView.saveState(webViewBundle);
    }
    }
```

**layout code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment2">
    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/tr" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView android:id="@+id/hu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ad9View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hi"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:adSize="BANNER" app:adUnitId="@string/ad9View" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad10View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ad9View"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:adSize="BANNER"

            app:adUnitId="@string/ad10View" />
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ad11View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ad10View"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:adUnitId="@string/ad11View" />
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ad12View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ad11View"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:adUnitId="@string/ad12View" />
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/earn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ad14View"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:adUnitId="@string/earn" />
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/earn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/earn1"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:adUnitId="@string/earn2" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/earn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/earn2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="@string/earn3" />
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/earn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/earn3"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:adUnitId="@string/earn4" />
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/earn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/earn4"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:adUnitId="@string/earn5" />
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ad13View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ad12View"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:adUnitId="@string/ad10View" />
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ad14View"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ad13View"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:adUnitId="@string/ad9View" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"

            android:layout_below="@id/hu"
            android:text="@string/text" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564808/show-progress-using-progressbar-for-webviewclient/44566746#44566746

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your fragment name, container, false);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
   progressBar.setMax(100);
   progressBar.setProgress(0 );
```

and then

```
@Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  }
```

at last

```
@Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

               progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you’re looking for is ProgressBar

You put the ProgressBar view in your XML layout and call progressbar.setVisibility(GONE) or VISIBLE depending on your needs

Comment: hi could you answer these question ??     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58267166/share-via-whatsapp-in-web-view                                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58271124/popup-inside-webview-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Add below `ProgressBar` to your `xml` layout.

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Step 2:**: Initialize `ProgressBar`

```
progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progress.setMax(100);
```

**Step 3:** Set client for your `WebView` and load the URL as shown below

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());
mWebView.loadUrl(your_url);
```

**Step 4:** Set progress as below. Hide it when progress is 100%.

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                WebViewActivity.this.setValue(newProgress);
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

                if (newProgress == 100){
                    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: hi could you answer these question ??     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58267166/share-via-whatsapp-in-web-view                                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58271124/popup-inside-webview-in-android-studio